# Trying to batch merge 2 .jpeg's horizontally and put them in a different folder after

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

this is for my doctoral thesis in medicine. So please excuse my noobishnis in programing.
I have a bunch (about 4000 files) of scans from patients. There is a front and a back .jpg for each patient. And there where multiple patients each day.
The folder structure looks like this:

```
\images
    \2017-08-21
              \pa_102165.jpg
              \pa_10216500001.jpg
    \2017-06-14
              \pa_101545.jpg
              \pa_10154500001.jpg
              \pa_104761.jpg
              \pa_10476100001.jpg
              \pa_107514.jpg
              \pa_10751400001.jpg
    \2017-03-73
              \pa_109631.jpg
              \pa_10963100001.jpg
              \pa_108624.jpg
              \pa_10862400001.jpg
```

Where in the first example `2017-08-21` is the date the patient came in, `pa_102165.jpg` is the front and `pa_10216500001.jpg` is the back. So the front is always `pa_10XXXX.jpg` and the back is `pa_10XXXX00001.jpg`. I had no hand in the nameing scheme.

My goal is to make a batchscript that merges the 2 corresponding .jpgs of each patient  horizontally and automatically puts them in a different folder, so that I don't have to do it manually with something like MS Paint.
For example like this:

```
\images
\merged
        \2017-08-21
                      \pa_102165_merged.jpg
        \2017-06-14
                      \pa_101545_merged.jpg
                      \pa_104761_merged.jpg
                      \pa_107514_merged.jpg
        \2017-03-73
                      \pa_109631_merged.jpg
                      \pa_108624_merged.jpg
```

I'm working on Windows 10 and found two promising methods so far but fail to comprehend how to make this into a batch file or something like it.

```
IrfanView Thumbnails
    1. Mark the 2 corresponding .jpgs
    2. File>Create contact sheet from selected files...
    3. Create
    4. File>Save as... in destination folder which i have to create for every day
```

which is faster than merging them by hand but would consume multiple workdays to do for all the pairs

and...

```
ImageMagic in Windows cmd
        C:\Users\me\doctor\Images\test\images\2016-03-31>convert pa_102165.jpg pa_10216500001.jpg +append pa_102165_merged.jpg
```

This produces the merged .jpeg in the same folder the input images are in. This looks more promising but I fail to grasp how I could automate this process given the nameing scheme and the folder structure.

Thanks for taking the time to read this! I'm happy for every input you have!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you fairly close. Essentially it is using the power of the `FOR` command modifiers to extract the base file name and file extension. The `FOR /F` command is capturing the output of the `DIR` command that is piped to the `FINDSTR` command.  We are doing that so we only grab files with the file mask of **pa_######.jpg**

Once we have that we use the command modifiers with the `IF` command to make sure the **00001** file exists.  If it does exist then it will execute the convert command. For the sake of making sure the code is performing correctly I am just `ECHOING` the output to the screen.  If the output on the screen looks correct then remove the `ECHO` so that the `CONVERT` command executes.

```
@echo off

CD /D "C:\Users\me\doctor\Images\test\images"

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /A-D /B /S PA_*.jpg ^|findstr /RIC:"pa_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.jpg$"') DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~dpnG00001%%~xG" (
        ECHO convert "%%G" "%%~dpnG00001%%~xG" +append "%%~dpnG_merged%%~xG"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This task could be done with *IrfanView* with the following batch file stored in the directory containing the folder `images`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "IrfanView=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe"
set "SourcePath=%~dp0images"
set "TargetPath=%~dp0merged"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R "%SourcePath%" pa_10????.jpg  2^>nul') do for %%J in ("%%~dpI.") do (
    if not exist "%TargetPath%\%%~nxJ\%%~nI_merged%%~xI" if exist "%%~dpnI00001%%~xI" (
        if not exist "%TargetPath%\%%~nxJ\" md "%TargetPath%\%%~nxJ"
        if exist "%TargetPath%\%%~nxJ\" (
            echo Merging "%%~nxJ\%%~nxI" and "%%~nxJ\%%~nI00001%%~xI" ...
            "%IrfanView%" /convert="%TargetPath%\%%~nxJ\%%~nI_merged%%~xI" /jpgq=95 /panorama=(1,"%%I","%%~dpnI00001%%~xI"^)
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

There must be customized the fully qualified file name of *IrfanView* in the third line. There can be modified also the percent value of option `/jpgq` which defines the quality of the output JPEG file.

The command **WHERE** searches recursive in subdirectory `images` of the directory containing the batch file for files matching the wildcard pattern `pa_10????.jpg` with ignoring all other files. The found file names are output with full path and this list of file names is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line after **WHERE** finished. **WHERE** is executed in this case by one more `cmd.exe` started in background with option `/c` and the command line within `'` as additional arguments and not by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `where` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Each image file with full name (drive + path + name + extension) is assigned one after the other to the loop variable `I`. For each file name one more **FOR** loop is used which processes just the full path to the current image file to assign this path with a dot appended to loop variable `J`. The dot at end means current directory, i.e. the directory containing current image file to process.

There is next checked with the first **IF** condition if for that image file does not exist already a matching `pa_10????_merged.jpg` file in which case there is nothing to do for the current image file. That means the batch file can be executed on same folder as often as wanted because of it runs *IrfanView* only for the source JPEG files for which the appropriate target JPEG file does not exist already.

The second **IF** condition checks if the back image exists also in the directory of current front image as otherwise nothing can be merged at all.

There is next checked with the third **IF** condition if the target directory exists already and this directory is created if that is not the case.

The last **IF** condition checks once again the existence of the target directory and if that exists now as expected, *IrfanView* is called with the appropriate options to create the merged image file in the target directory with the appropriate file name.

The closing round bracket `)` on *IrfanView* command line must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted literally by `cmd.exe` to pass this closing parenthesis to *IrfanView* instead of interpreting it as end of one of the command blocks opened with `(` above.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file path always ending with a backslash
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `where /?`

Double click on the text file `i_options.txt` in program files folder of *IrfanView* for the description of the *IrfanView* options as used in the batch file.

Comment: Thank you so much. This does exactly what I needed to! I only needed to edit the Irfanview path. This probably saved me weeks of gruntwork